# Unable to render data in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I am new to react and have been debugging this from yesterday and I finally decide to post as I am clueless of what is happening.

The following react code fetches data from the api and then renders it on the UI. But, **there are few strange things happening here.**

I get error saying as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` initially but when I comment out `{renderTableData(data)}`& save and then again uncomment & save, `the data is rendering perfectly on the UI`

[image]

I am thinking that before even the data gets fetched from API, it is getting passed to the function `renderTableData` which is why in the console `undefined` is printed.

Here is the code

```
export default function TenantList(){
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
      }).then((data)=>{
        setData(data)
      })
    },[]);
 
function renderTableData(data) {
  console.log("hello ", data)
  return data.map((student, index) => {
      const { name, email } = student //destructuring
      return (
          <tr key={name}>
              <td>{name}</td>
              <td>{email}</td>
          </tr>
      )
  })
}
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {renderTableData(data)}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Please suggest a workaround

Comment: Try adding `console.log(data)` in your useEffect right before the `setData(data)` line and tell me what it logs.

Comment: If you have `useState([]);` then it should not be happening, as the initial value of `data` is an array.

Comment: @aryanm I have written `console.log(data)` before  setData but nothing got printed

Comment: @aryanm @Gabriele,  As @jmargolisvt suggested in the answer, when I wrote `{data && renderTableData(data)}
` It is rendering perfectly even on page refresh

Comment: It should work without it. Something else is not right in your code if you keep getting that error. See https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-sun-1ukiw?file=/src/App.js it is your code and works just fine.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli yes on codesandbox it is working fine, but in my local machine, it is giving such behaviour.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli but adding `{data && renderTableData(data)}` is an added advantage right in any case?

Comment: Sure, you could also just give a default value to the argument like `function renderTableData(data = []) {`.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thanks. When I pass `data = []` it the function will wait till the data is not empty?

Comment: It will not wait (*and nor does it wait now*), but if the argument passed is `undefined` it will become `[]` which means the `map` will be available.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli ok, got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to run this function if you have the data, so check for it:

```
{data && renderTableData(data)}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much man :) I literally got backpain sitting for hours to figure this out. You are a saviour

Comment: Accepted. There was a time limit to accept the answer so couldn't do it till now